# Mosby and restoring state after orientation change

Tags: mosby, android-mvp

In our app (which uses Mosby) we have a SearchActivity that uses Retrofit to fetch results.
The basic flow currently is that the SearchActivity has a `List<Results>` (which has a `@State` annotation) which I add the retrieved results.
From the SearchActivity I do a call to `presenter.doSearch(searchquery)`
In our Retrofit `onSuccess` callback I then call `getView().populateResults(results)`.
This then adds the retrieved results to the List in the activity and also adds to the recycler view.

This is not the correct way to do it because we now get TransactionTooLargeExcpetion's.

So then what is the correct way using Mosby of saving those fetched results and restoring them on orientation change.

Comment: Which ViewState implementation class do you use?

Comment: currently we are not using any viewstate class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really Mosby related. It seems that you store too much data in Bundle (has a limit of 1MB or 512kb depending on Android Version). You better cache your result in a disk cache and reload them ...